# recursive statistics on file types in directory?

Tags: shell, filenames

I did a website scrape for a conversion project. I'd like to do some statistics on the types of files in there -- for instance, 400 `.html` files, 100 `.gif`, etc. What's an easy way to do this? It has to be recursive.

**Edit:** With the script that maxschelpzig posted, I'm having some problems due to the architecture of the site I've scraped. Some of the files are of the name `*.php?blah=blah&foo=bar` with various arguments, so it counts them all as unique. So the solution needs to consider `*.php*` to be all of the same type, so to speak.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You could use `find` and `uniq` for this, e.g.:

```
$ find . -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c
   16 avi
   29 jpg
  136 mp3
    3 mp4
```

Command explanation

- `find` recursively prints all filenames
- `sed` deletes from every filename the prefix until the file extension
- `uniq` assumes sorted input

  - `-c` does the counting (like a histogram).

Comment: I have a similar script. Simple and fast.

Comment: Some of the files are of the name `*.php?blah=blah&foo=bar` with various arguments, so it counts them all as unique. How can I modify it to look for `*.php*`?

Comment: You can try to use a different sed expression, e.g. `sed 's/^.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\).*$/\1/'`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain what each portion does. So many answers on similar topics skip this part.  /learning-to-fish

Comment: A way to ignore hidden files such as .git?

Comment: @Vadorequest, you can modify the `find` call - e.g. use something like `find -name '.*' -prune -o -type f -print`.

Comment: @maxschlepzig If you want to use the (very useful) command above, there is a blatant typo : it should be `find -name '*.*' -prune -o -type f -print`.

Comment: @bela83, I don't thing that your version yields the desired results - it also prunes too much. My version from my last comment prunes too much, as well (it prunes also `.`) - a better version should be: `find -name '.*' -not -name . -prune -o -type f -print`

Comment: @maxschlepzig I'm sorry, I mixed up different questions. My command returns file with an extension (I think). Yours returns non-hidden files. I will try to find the one that returns non-hidden files with an extension.

Comment: `find -name '.*' -prune -o -type f -print` doesn't return anything, which surprises me. I am using `findutils: Installed: 4.4.2-9build1`

Comment: @bela83, the prune variants rely on [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - thus, my first version `find -name '.*' -prune -o -type f -print` evaluates like: if directory entry matches `.*` then prune it, otherwise if it is a file then print it. Since `.*` also matches `.`, i.e. the CWD, everything is pruned, i.e. find does not even descend into the first directory. Perhaps, 2 year old versions of `find` behaved differently - or it was just an oversight of me, back then. Anyhow, `find -name '.*' -not -name . -prune -o -type f -print` fixes this.

Comment: Very good ! I'll have to investigate further the `prune` option.

Comment: How can I modify this to include the total size of each file type as well?

Comment: @kraftydevil, I suggest that you post a new question for this.

Comment: to avoid mismatch on files with more than one '.', try this:

    `find . -type f | grep -oP '(\..{3,4})$' | sort | uniq -c | sort -hr`

Comment: I suggest using `awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'` instead of your `sed 's/.*\.//'`. That way you will cover the files that have dot in their names as well.

Comment: @deimos Did you test your suggestion? Both commands are equivalent because sed greedily matches the regular expression.

Comment: @MechEthan you can use [explainshell](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-type+f+%7C+sed+%27s%2F.*%5C.%2F%2F%27+%7C+sort+%7C+uniq+-c)

Answer (score 6):

With zsh¹:

```
print -rl -- **/?*.*(D.:e) | uniq -c |sort -n
```

The [pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) `**/?*.*` matches all files that have an extension, in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively. The `D` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) lets `zsh` traverse even hidden directories and consider hidden files, The `.` one selects only regular files. The `:e` [modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) retains only the file extension. `print -rl` prints one match per line. `uniq -c` counts consecutive identical items (the glob result is already sorted). The final call to `sort` sorts the extensions by use count.

---

<sup>¹ and assuming file extensions don't contain newline characters.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

This one-liner seems to be a fairly robust method:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed -r -n 's/.+(\..*)$/\1/p' | sort | uniq -c
```

The `find . -type f -printf '%f\n'` prints the basename of every regular file in the tree, with no directories.  That eliminates having to worry about directories which may have `.`'s in them in your `sed` regex.

The `sed -r -n 's/.+(\..*)$/\1/p'` replaces the incoming filename with only its extension.  E.g., `.somefile.ext` becomes `.ext`.  Note the initial `.+` in the regex; this results in any match needing at least one character before the extension's `.`.  This prevents filenames like `.gitignore` from being treated as having no name at all and the extension '.gitignore', which is probably what you want.  If not, replace the `.+` with a `.*`.

The rest of the line is from the accepted answer.

**Edit**: If you want a nicely-sorted histogram in [Pareto chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_chart) format, just add another `sort` to the end:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed -r -n 's/.+(\..*)$/\1/p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -bn
```

Sample output from a built Linux source tree:

```
    1 .1992-1997
    1 .1994-2004
    1 .1995-2002
    1 .1996-2002
    1 .ac
    1 .act2000
    1 .AddingFirmware
    1 .AdvancedTopics
    [...]
 1445 .S
 2826 .o
 2919 .cmd
 3531 .txt
19290 .h
23480 .c
```

Answer (score 2):

I've put a bash script into my `~/bin` folder called `exhist` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */ ; do
        echo $d
        find $d -type f | sed -r 's/.*\/([^\/]+)/\1/' | sed 's/^[^\.]*$//' | sed -r 's/.*(\.[^\.]+)$/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
#       files only      | keep filename only          | no ext -> '' ext   | keep part after . (i.e. ext) | count          | sort by count desc
done
```

Whichever directory I'm in, I just type 'exh', tab auto-completes it, and I see something like this:

```
$ exhist
src/
      7 .java
      1 .txt
target/
     42 .html
     10 .class
      4 .jar
      3 .lst
      2 
      1 .xml
      1 .txt
      1 .properties
      1 .js
      1 .css
```

P.S. Trimming the part after the question mark should be simple to do with another sed command probably after the last one (I haven't tried it): `sed 's/\?.*//'`

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but, this is one of top results when searching for "bash count file extensions".

I encountered the same problem as you and created a script similar to maxschlepzig

Here is the command i made that counts the extensions of all files in the working directory recursively.
This takes into account UPPER, and LOWER cases, merging them, removing false positive results, and counting the occurrences.

```
find . -type f \
  | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' \
  | grep -E ".*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" \
  | sed -e 's/.*\(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/\1/' \
  | sort |
  | uniq -c \
  | sort -n
```

Here is the github link if you'd like to see more documentation.

https://github.com/Hoppi164/list_file_extensions

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of maxschlepzig's answer:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/.*\(\.\)/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1nr
```

Or if your `find` doesn't support `-printf` you can use follow instead:

```
find . -type f | sed 's/.*\///' | sed 's/.*\(\.\)/\1/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1nr
```

The result is sorted by count desc like this:

```
3500 .html
524 .pdf
167 .in
160 .ans
156 .ppt
144 .doc
71 .png
65 .js
56 .jpg
47 .css
44 .pas
38 .gif
34 .PDF
32 .txt
1 RELEASENOTES
1 .bak
```