# List all file extensions in an arborescence and count number of occurences of each

Tags: bash

I am looking for a simple shell function (bash prefered) to list all file extensions in an arborescence and count the number of occurences of each.

For example, `list_extensions .` would return something like :

```
pdf 134
tex 42
cpp 30
...
```

A plus would be to also count the file without extensions.

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks ! The first link does the job. Do you know how I could address the "files without extensions" problem ?

Comment: I'd use something like `find . -type f ! -name '*.*' -print0 | grep -cz .` to count them.

Comment: @don_crissti Would you care to expand on the `cz` flags ? I would gladly accept this as an answer.

Comment: It's there (together with `-print0`) to deal with file names containing newlines, e.g. find prints the file names null delimited and grep `c`ounts the matching lines treating them as null delimited (`-z`) instead of newline delimited. If you don't have such file names you can simply run `find . -type f ! -name '*.*' | grep -c .` or `find . -type f ! -name '*.*' | wc -l` which means print all file names that don't have a dot in their name (one per line) and then count the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As don_crissti stated in a comment, this question is a duplicate and the answer can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/recursive-statistics-on-file-types-in-directory). However, you also want to count files without extensions. This is my go at it:

```
echo no_ext $(find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $(basename "{}")' \; | grep -v '\.' | wc -l)
```

I'll try to explain the subsequent commands and their purpose.

First, we use find to find regular files and forward their respective paths through the basename command in a rather cumbersome way.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo $(basename "{}")' \;
```

Secondly, we can then simply search for filenames without a period in them, using grep in invert mode.

```
grep -v
```

The last step is to count the number of rows.

```
wc -l
```

This can be feeded into echo. Combining all of this results in the command above.

EDIT: I use [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) to concatenate a label, in this case 'no_ext' to the computed number. You can also run the command between the parentheses by itself without the echo to only print the computed number.

Comment: Very good. I understand well `find` `grep` and `wc`. But what is the use of the construct `echo no_ext $()` ?

Comment: In unix shells, like bash, you can use either the used dollar notation or, equivalently, use the backtick notation (like: echo no_ext `find . -type ...`) to perform command substitution. This causes the command to be executed and be substituted with it's output in-place. Or in other words: I am printing 'no_ext' (for 'no extension') using echo and I concatenate to it the output of the long command (the number of files without extension).