# ls option to list files without reference to extension?

Tags: file-management

We use a numeric version control for files (ex: report01.log.01, report01.log.02, report01.log.03, etc.)

What I need to do is produce a list each file and the number of versions the file has.

Does Linux has a function to do this relatively easily?

Comment: See [Recursive statistics on file types in directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18506) - instead of extracting the part after the last dot you just have to extract the part before it. Other than that it's the same...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give an example of the output you want to see.

Comment: Consider using a Perl or Python script for this.  It will be more maintainable than the shell scripts various people have suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach : `ls | cut -f1 -d. | uniq -c`.

`awk` approach : `ls | awk -F. '{a[$1]++}END{for(b in a){print b,a[b]}}'`

(long winded) `perl` approach : `ls|perl -e 'while(<>){$a{(split(/\./,$_))[0]}++}for(sort keys %a){print "$_ $a{$_}\n"}'`

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants to remove the last dot-delimited part, while you only keep the first one.

Answer (score 5):

I'd advise against parsing the output of `ls`, `find`, etc (see [ParsingLs - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for an explanation of why that's a bad idea).

Instead, [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) on a bash array can produce a list without the file extensions.

```
filelist=(*);                      # or filelist=(*.log.*) to be more precise
printf '%q\n' "${filelist[@]%.*}"  # or echo "${filelist[@]%.*}"
```

Then, to work on the files individually ..

```
for i in "${filelist[@]%.*}"; do
   echo "$i";
done
```

For OP's particular purpose, we can use a bash [associative array](http://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/) to hold the count of versions.

```
filelist=(*.log.*)

declare -A count
for i in "${filelist[@]%.*}"; do 
  (( count["$i"]++ )); 
done

for j in "${!count[@]}"; do 
  printf '%q\t%q\n' "$j" "${count[$j]}";
done | sort

report01.log    6
report02.log    6
report03.log    6
report04.log    6
report05.log    6
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like `ls | sed -e 's/\.[0-9]\+$//' | sort | uniq -c` should do what you want.

Comment: This is obviously a quick&dirty way to do this.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with quick&dirty.

Comment: I think it’s up to the OP to decide if quick&dirty is good enough for him, but shalomb is right that it’s better not to parse the output of `ls`, so I’d rather recommend his solution than mine or steve’s.